# Is the determinant of a matrix lower when all its elements are lower?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

**Problem**

Consider a generic matrix $A$, we are going to think of a simple case by taking into consideration a $3 \times 3$ matrix:

$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & a_{1,3}\\
a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & a_{2,3}\\
a_{3,1} & a_{3,2} & a_{3,3}\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Consider now having $A'$ as:

$$
A' = \begin{pmatrix}
a'_{1,1} & a'_{1,2} & a'_{1,3}\\
a'_{2,1} & a'_{2,2} & a'_{2,3}\\
a'_{3,1} & a'_{3,2} & a'_{3,3}\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The following holds:

$$a'_{i,j} \leq a_{i,j}$$

**Question**

I would like to know if the following:

$$|A'| \leq |A|$$

If it holds, can you prove it?

**Another problem**

What if we considered:

$$
a_{i,j} \leq 1, a'_{i,j} \leq 1
$$

Considering also that $A$ is a stochastic matrix?

This does not mean that both $A$ and $A'$ are stochastic. I am considering $A$ stochastic and $A'$ obtained as a reduced version of $A$ so that $A'$ is not stochastic but its values are all between 0 and 1.

Comment: In general, the determinant of an $n\times n$ matrix is a rather complicated polynomial in the $a_{ij}$, and certainly there's no reason to expect this to be increasing with respect to all variables.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The claim is false. For instance $$A' = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$ and $$A = \begin{pmatrix}2 & 2 & 2\\2 & 2 & 2\\2 & 2 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$$
Clearly, $A'_{ij} \leq A_{ij}$, whereas $$\det(A') = 1 > 0 \det(A)$$

**EDIT**

If $A$ and $A'$ are both stochastic matrices, then $A'_{ij} \leq A_{ij}$ gives us $A'_{ij} = A_{ij}$ since $$1 = \displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{3} A'_{ij} \leq \sum_{j=1}^{3} A_{ij} = 1, \,\forall i \in \{1,2,3\}$$

**EDIT**

If $A$ is stochastic, but $A'$ is not stochastic, then again it is false. For instance, $$A = \begin{pmatrix}\frac13 & \frac13 & \frac13\\\frac13 & \frac13 & \frac13\\\frac13 & \frac13 & \frac13 \end{pmatrix}$$
and $$A' = \begin{pmatrix}\frac13 & 0 & 0\\0 & \frac13 & 0\\0 & 0 & \frac13 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: It looks like we came up with the same example:-)

Comment: @algebra_fan :) Interesting.

Comment: Thank you :) What if A were stochastic?

Comment: Please read more carefully, now I pointed it better but before I stated that A only is stochastic.

Answer (score 6):

This is false. Let $A$ be the matrix all of whose entries are equal to $2$ and $A'$ be the identity matrix. Note that $\det(A) = 0$ since its columns are linearly dependent, while $\det(A') = 1$.

Comment: Thank you very much, please see edits.

Comment: If $A$ and $A'$ are stochastic, then $A = A'$ as Marvis showed in the response above.

Comment: No I said that only A is stochastic :P